# Spring Flux ( or Java Stream ) merged as a left join

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, java-stream, spring-webflux

How can I join this two Flux

```
val a: Flux<String> = Flux.just("foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar")
val b: Flux<Pair<String, Int>> = Flux.just( Pair("foo", 5), Pair("baz", 5))
```

to have an output another Flux as this ?

```
val c: Flux<Pair<String, Int>> = Flux.just(
    Pair("foo", 5),
    Pair("bar", 0),
    Pair("baz", 5),
    Pair("foobar",0)
)
```

In plain words, I need all the element of A, with the values of B if exists, zero/null otherwise, like a sql left join

I'm looking at `zip`, `zipWith`, `merge` but I'm a bit confused. Any hint ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     Flux.from(a)
                .map(s -> {
                    return b.filter(strPair -> s.equals(strPair.fst)).switchIfEmpty(Flux.just(Pair.of(s,0)));
                }).flatMap(Flux::next).log().subscribe();
```

output:

```
10:26:00.358 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.3 - request(unbounded)
10:26:00.591 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.3 - onNext(Pair[foo,5])
10:26:00.593 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.3 - onNext(Pair[bar,0])
10:26:00.594 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.3 - onNext(Pair[baz,5])
10:26:00.594 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.3 - onNext(Pair[foobar,0])
10:26:00.594 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.FlatMap.3 - onComplete()
```

Comment: And this is the correct Spring Flux solution ! I was looking to the wrong functions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not very familiar with Kotlin, yet since you've asked for either stream solution as well, you can draw a similarity to the following sample:

```
List<String> list = List.of("foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar");
List<Pair<String, Integer>> pairs = List.of(Pair.of("foo", 5), Pair.of("baz", 5));
List<Pair<String, Integer>> result = list.stream()
    .map(a ->
        pairs.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getLeft().equals(a))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(Pair.of(a, 0)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```